# Cant access object vars

Tags: php, object, properties

I know I'm going to get some downvotes on this one but I'm not being lazy. I legitimately tried finding this out without resorting to asking a question.

```
 var_dump($vtest);

object(Vocation)#58 (5) {
 ["attributes"]=>
 array(11) {
 ["id"]=>
 string(3) "623"
["resource_id"]=>
string(4) "6111"
["dry_van"]=>
string(1) "1"
["refridgerate"]=>
string(1) "1"
["parcel"]=>
string(1) "0"
["f&b"]=>
string(1) "1"
["tanker"]=>
string(1) "1"
["energy"]=>
string(1) "1"
["construction"]=>
string(1) "1"
["fleet"]=>
string(0) ""
["all_vocations"]=>
string(1) "1"
}
```

why can't I access this using `$vtest->id`

I get:
`Trying to get property of non-object`

Answer (score 1):

You want `$vtest->attributes['id']`. If you actually read the output of `var_dump`, you can see that `id` is nested within `attributes`, which is an array.

Comment: This also gives me: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like:

`$vtest['attributes']['id']`

Comment: this one gives me: Cannot use object of type Vocation as array

Comment: Then meagar's answer should do it. Are you sure these attributes are defined as public?

Comment: yes, they are and his answer doesnt work, I get the same error, trying to access property of non object. Which is weird because it is def an object

Comment: Hmm... what about `$vtest->attributes->id`? Also, try printing with `print_r($vtest)` to see what it says.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Alejandro. That code gives the same error,  trying to access property of non object.

Comment: Vocation Object
(
    [attributes] => Array
        (
            [id] => 623
            [resource_id] => 6111
            [dry_van] => 1
            [refridgerate] => 1
            [parcel] => 0
            [f&b] => 1
            [tanker] => 1
            [energy] => 1
            [construction] => 1
            [fleet] => 
            [all_vocations] => 1
        )

Comment: Do you have the definition of your class? This is weird